# AWS CLI won't detect / accept credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-machine

I'm playing around with AWS and my credentials worked few months back. I'm using credentials file located in ~/.aws/credentials
and using the keys provided by AWS. They updated the access key so I've changed it in the file but secret key remained the same.

I've got the credentials file in this format:

```
[default] 
aws_access_key_id=xyz
aws_secret_access_key=xyz
region=eu-west-2
vpc-id=xyz
```

when I run `docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 testdriven-prod`
I get this output:

```
Error setting machine configuration from flags provided: amazonec2 driver requires AWS credentials configured with the --amazonec2-access-key and --amazonec2-secret-key options, environment variables, ~/.aws/credentials, or an instance role
```

The file is in the right directory though. Why Docker-machine can't see it ? I really don't understand this error.

What can I try to resolve this ?

Comment: If access key has changed, secret key has also changed. Since you are using a default profile, try running the command: `aws sts get-caller-identity` and see if it returns a response with account number and IAM user details or does it throw an error.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004  that command outputs `Partial credentials found in shared-credentials-file, missing: aws_secret_access_key`  strangely, the secret key isn't missing.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 I edited the file a little bit I now get correct output running that command however I still get the same error when running `docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 testdriven-prod`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a real answer rather a find.

I used verbose cli command to create the instance and it worked. Even though
this:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key XYZ --amazonec2-secret-key XYZ --amazonec2-open-port 8000 --amazonec2-region eu-west-2 testdriven-prod
```

should be equivalent to:

```
aws_access_key_id=XYZ
aws_secret_access_key=XYZ
region=eu-west-2
```

in ~/.aws/credentials file the behaviour was different.
So if anyone is still interested in sharing what the real answer to this might
be please feel free to post it.